# Scrapy grabbing elements too deep in table

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, html-table, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a table with Scrapy, and have come across an issue in which I'm getting too many child nodes because of the structure of the table.

For instance, there is a table in a td later in the table, sort of like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
             Text I want
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Text I do not want
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </td>
</table>
```

So when I tell it to grab:

```
td[1]/text()
```

It grabs the text in the first td of each tr — which is exactly what I want — but some of the tds have their own table! Don't ask me why they built this thing this way, or why there is literally not a class or id to be found any deeper than the table level itself, but that's how it is. So I'm also returning the text in the first td inside the table... that's in the later tds that I don't want (yet).

Without ids or classes, how can I get more specific about wanting only that first td's text and not anything that's any deeper in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options to proceed with:

- use relative xpath to the top level `td` (no absolute `//` that will cause recursive search):

  ```
  /path_to_table/table/tr/td[1]/text()
  ```
- check that `td` has only one `table` among it's ancestors:

  ```
  //td[count(ancestor::table) = 1]/text()
  ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because you have this somewhere in your query:

```
table//td[1]/text()
```

`//td` means finding all `td` at any level of children.

Change it to:

```
table/tr/td[1]/text()
```

or if you have `tbody`

```
table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()
```

This will get `td`s which are immediate children of your `table`.